# Using the physics package to take second derivatives with respect to primed coordinates

Tags: superscripts, physics

As it says in the title, I am attempting to write a second derivative such as the following

[image]

and ideally would use the shorthand derivative from the physics package which would be the following.

`\dv[2]{x'}{t'}`

However, the returns a "Double superscript" error because of the prime in the denominator. Obviously, this can be avoided by writing it out explicitly with \frac. However I was wondering if there was a simpler solution.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty brace group at end of final argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\[\dv[2]{x'}{t'{}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative would be to enclose the last argument in an extra set of braces, but this changes the superscript height

```
\[\dv[2]{x'}{{t'}}\]
```